# How can I get the value of a xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute using XDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have lots of XML files which have various xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation values. Thse are in attributes in the root node of the documents. I need to read the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation values from the files. This shouldn't be difficult but I'm struggling.

Example XML (this is the root node):

```
<books xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.someSchemaLocation.xsd">
```

It's the value of **xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation** that i'm looking for.

I can do :

```
string blah = myXdocument.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi").NamespaceName;
```

and this returns `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`as you'd expect.

I've tried:

```
string test = myXdocument.Root.Attribute("xsi" + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation").Value.ToString();
```

but that returns null.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `blah` to `XNamespace`:

```
string test = myXdocument.Root.Attribute((XNamespace)blah + "noNamespaceSchemaLocation")
    .Value.ToString();
```